# How to modify variable defined in script block in declarative pipeline of jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have declared a variable *TENTATIVE_VERSION* in my script, and **I need** to define/modify it with the value coming from executing a script (or from the script itself in other stage), **how can I do this**?  my current script is something like this:

```
pipeline {
agent {
    label 'machine1'
}
stages {
    stage('Non-Parallel Stage') {
        agent{label "machine2"}
        steps {
            script {
                TENTATIVE_VERSION="1.0" // working
                // TENTATIVE_VERSION="sh echo 123" //not working
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Parallel Stage') {
        parallel {
            stage('A') {
                agent {label 'machine3'}
                steps {
                    echo "On other machine"
                    echo "${TENTATIVE_VERSION}"
                    build job: 'otherJob', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'VERSION', value: "${TENTATIVE_VERSION}"],
                    [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'RELEASE', value: '1']]
                }
            }
            stage('B') {
                agent {label "machine4"}
                steps {
                    script {
                        STATUS_S = "OK"
                    }
                    echo "On a machine"
                }
            }
            stage('C') {
                agent {label "machine5"}
                steps {
                    script {
                        STATUS_R = "OK"
                    }
                    echo "On a machine"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following:

```
pipeline {
agent {
    label 'machine1'
}
stages {
    stage('Non-Parallel Stage') {
        agent{label "machine2"}
        steps {
            script {
                TENTATIVE_VERSION = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "echo 123").trim()
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```